# Can I specify default "using"s to be added by resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper, using

By default, Resharper does not specify any `using`s in .cs files. Is it possible to configure it to add one or two `using`s by default

Comment: Why do you want to? Why not let ReSharper add them as needed?

Comment: @JohnSaunders specifically, I want Linq extension methods for collections to be available in intellisense. This isn't the case if `System.Linq` isn't imported. Is there any drawback of always importing `System.Linq`?

Comment: hat version of ReSharper are you using? For the last several major releases, if you type the name of the class you're looking for, and if the assembly containing the class is referenced, then R# will ask your permission to import the assembly with `using`.

Comment: I want the extension methods to be in Intellisense, not to auto-import assembly by typing classname.

Comment: Whe.n I type the name if the extension metod the first time, it prompts me to import System.Linq

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, but I often don't remember the name of some methods and I prefer it always exist in Intellisense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can use a special kind of intellisense called `Import symbol` (Shift-Alt-Space) instead. It would show you all available methods regardless of their namespace and then it would import everything.

But if you still want additional usings, then in addition to advice from @Hadi Eskandari I can suggest to go to `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Namespace imports` and add your namespaces to "Namespaces that should always be imported". This way ReSharper would not suggest to remove your namespaces and would always add them during Code Cleanup.

Comment: I see. Is there any downside to always importing one or two namespaces?

Comment: You might have members with the same names in other namespaces, and they would conflict. But if it's only standard and widely used namespaces such as LINQ, then I don't really see any downsides to having them always imported.

Answer (score 2):

Goto ***Resharper -> Template Explorer...*** menu and from there choose ***File Templates*** tab and on the screen select ***Class*** template and customize that. Now when you create a new class using Resharper's ***New From Template*** item in the context menu, you'll get the template you want.